# Can a valid SSL Certificate cause a Certificate Error if the DNS name used in the CSR is pending association with the machine it is to be used?

Tags: ssl, dns, iis-8, csr

Currently in the process of moving an existing public facing site from Azure to our internal network. In order to retain the validity of the SSL (https) protocol I had to request another certificate for the the machine where the new site will reside.

I installed the cert on the system and it says it installed successfully but the site is showing a Certificate error in IE.

So I'm wondering if the fact that the CSR was created using the DNS name and the DNS hasn't yet been redirected to the new location; is the reason the Cert Error is being displayed?

The only way to access the new server is via IP address externally, not by the DNS name.

Does the site certificate get bound during creation to the DNS name of the server where it is supposed to reside or by the encrypted signature of the actual machine when the CSR (Certificate Signing Request) is generated?

Or is it both?

Comment: Sounds like you are running a virtual machine on Azure. Then run SSL Diagnostics to see if there is any obvious error, https://www.jexusmanager.com/en/latest/tutorials/ssl-diagnostics.html

Comment: @LexLi The site without the issue is an Azure cloud service, the site where the issue is prevalent is a Windows VM server. But I will definitely look into the link provided as it may prove to be useful in future troubleshooting

Comment: For HTTPS see [section 3.1 of RFC 2818](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2818#section-3.1). Whatever hostname the client uses in the URI MUST appear in the common name of the subject and/or one of the subject alternative names. While IP addresses are permitted by the RFC, in practice no CA will or should issue a cert with an IP address for a hostname.  As a temporary workaround, you can map the dns name to an IP address in something like /etc/hosts. There are many ways to do this and they tend to be os- and tool- specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The only way to access the new server is via IP address externally, not by the DNS name.

I'm not fully sure what you are asking. But my interpretation of the question is that you have created a certificate for some DNS name (i.e. `example.com`) but then try to access the site by IP address since the DNS name is not available yet. And then you wonder why the browser complains (with an error you unfortunately not include in your question).

If my interpretation is correct then the reason for the browser error is that the hostname in the URL (i.e. the IP address you used) does not match the subject(s) of the certificate, i.e. the DNS name. This validation of name in URL against subject of certificate is an essential part of the certificate validation.

Comment: Thank you for the response. That is precisely the question I was asking but apparently didn't do a very eloquent job explaining. I didn't include the error because it didn't seem to be something I considered to add any additional value to the question but I should have provided it anyway. So in short, the certificate is bound to the DNS name as well as the digital signature of the server.  Perfect, thx!

Comment: @Mark: *"... as well as the digital signature of the server"* - your probably mean the private key of the server, which is used within the SSL handshake to create kind of a digital signature but is not the digital signature itself.